# Maximum value for n_clusters in K Means algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a dataset with 28000 records. The data is of an e-commerce store menu items. The challenge is the following:

> Multiple stores have similar products but with different names. For example, 'HP laptop 1102' is present in different stores as 'HP laptop 1102', 'Hewlett-Packard laptop 1102', 'HP notebook 1102' and many other different names.

I have opted to convert the product list as a tfidf vector and use KMeans clustering to group similar products together. I am also using some other features like product category, sub category etc. (I have one hot encoded all the categorical features)

Now my challenge is to estimate the optimal n_clusters in KMeans algorithm. As the clustering should occur at product level, I'm assuming I need a high n_clusters value. Is there any upper limit for the n_clusters?

Also any suggestions and advice on the solution approach would be really helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are optimising for k, so you could try an approach similiar to this one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075481/how-do-i-cluster-a-list-of-geographic-points-by-distance/53179675#53179675

Answer (score 0):

You are optimising for k, so you could try an approach similar to this one here: [how do I cluster a list of geographic points by distance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075481/how-do-i-cluster-a-list-of-geographic-points-by-distance/53179675#53179675)

As for max k, you can only every have as many clusters as you do datapoints, so try using that as your upper bound

Answer (score 0):

The upper limit is the number of data points, but you almost surely want a number a good bit lower for clustering to provide any value. If you have 10,000 products I would think 5,000 clusters would be a rough maximum from a usefulness standpoint.

You can use the *silhouette score* and *inertia* metrics to help determine the optimal number of clusters.

> The Silhouette Coefficient is calculated using the mean intra-cluster distance (a) and the mean nearest-cluster distance (b) for each sample. The Silhouette Coefficient for a sample is (b - a) / max(a, b). To clarify, b is the distance between a sample and the nearest cluster that the sample is not a part of....
> The best value is 1 and the worst value is -1. Values near 0 indicate overlapping clusters. - from the [scikit-learn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html)

*inertia*_ is an attribute of a fitted clustering object in scikit-learn - not a separate evaluation metric.
It is the "Sum of squared distances of samples to their closest cluster center."  - see the [KMeans clustering docs in scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html), for example.

Note that inertia increases as you add more clusters, so you may want to use an elbow plot to visualize where the change becomes minimal.